# Sending e-mails with SMTP from PHP on Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, smtp

I having problems sending e-mails from my PHP application coded with CodeIgniter framework. I've a fresh install of Ubuntu Server on a VMWare with Apache, PHP and MySQL. The error I get is the next:

```
220 linux11.dns-servicios.com ESMTP

hello: 250-linux11.dns-servicios.com Hello a.b.c.kion.es [83.49.x.y]
250-SIZE 31457280
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP

from: 250 OK

to: 550-Verification failed for 
550-mensaje de error"
550 Sender verify failed

The following SMTP error was encountered: 550-Verification failed for 550-mensaje de error" 550 Sender verify failed

data: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
503-Sender verify failed
503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA

The following SMTP error was encountered: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error: 503-Sender verify failed 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
500 unrecognized command
The following SMTP error was encountered: 500 unrecognized command
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

What can I do?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the code, not the server.

```
to: 550-Verification failed for 
550-mensaje de error"
550 Sender verify failed
```

It looks like you are setting the 'To' to 'mensaje de error"' and obviously this is not an email address.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily solve this problem by using google.  The error is plainly shown:

```
550 Sender verify failed
```

Comment: I am not sure why someone deducted a point here.  Part of helping people is teaching them how to help themselves.

Comment: I didn't mark your answer down, but can say this.  Think of someone hunting Google for a similar issue.  The top result is this page.  They get to this page only to find the only answer is to go back to Google.  Not very helpful is it?  The point of this site is to answer the questions definitively, as a resource for everyone, not just the original poster.  If you think the OP didn't try hard enough, leave a comment, vote down their question, flag it, or move on leaving it for someone else, or oblivion.